# How to test Delete method in controller with Mockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I don't know how to create the unit test for my controller with Delete Method.

//Controller class

```
@PostMapping("delete")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteClient(@RequestBody DeleteClientModel deleteClientModel){
        clientService.deleteClientById(deleteClientModel.getId());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

//Service class

```
 public void deleteClientById(int id) {
        clientRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
```

As you can see the method doesn't return anything so that's why I don't know how to test the controller class. Please help me

Here's a test

```
@Test
    public void ClientController_deleteClient() throws Exception{
        ???
    }
```

Comment: The controller itself doesn't execute any logic. you would rather test the service class in that case. Also you can always perform a search after the delete, which shouldn't return anything as its deleted

Comment: Use `Mockito.verify` to check that `deleteById` was called on your mock `clientService` with the expected id.

Comment: Thank you for the answers but maybe you know how use ResultActions result = mockMVC.perform(post("/delete").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)); in this case?

Comment: If you want to do a Rest Call using mockMVC then you can not use mockito. Depending on how much you want to test you need to create a `@WebMvcTest` or a `@SpringBootTest` .

Answer (score 0):

You can use MockMvcRequestBuilder to run controller tests in springboot as below

include the gradle dependency,
`testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')`

```
 @WebMvcTest(ClientController.class)
 public class TestClientController {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    public void ClientController_deleteClient() throws Exception 
    {
      DeleteClientModel deleteClientModel = new DeleteClientModel();
      deleteClientModel.setId("100");

      mvc.perform( MockMvcRequestBuilders
              .post("/delete")
              .content(asJsonString(deleteClientModel))
              .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
              .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
              .andExpect(status().isOk())
     }

    public static String asJsonString(final Object obj) {
      try {
         return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(obj);
      } catch (Exception e) {
         throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
    }
 }
```

Hope this helped :)